# Simple schematic for 10.7 MHz crystal-based marker generator

Tags: oscillator, frequency-modulation

For FM tuner alignment purposes I want to build an outboard 10.7 MHz marker generator to use in association with a piece of gear (ST1000A) that doesn't have one built in. They used to be available in little battery powered boxes with BNC in and out. Can someone direct me to a schematic? Also construction information, e.g. any RF precautions I may need to take. Planning a metal hobby box.

Editing this to make it crystal clear that I am not seeking a product or product recommendation. Frankly it baffles me how anybody thought otherwise, unless they just didn't read it.

Comment: To whomever voted to close -- the OP isn't looking to purchase a marker generator (which would be off-topic), instead he appears to want to build one and is looking for help.

Comment: Try this: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=10.7MHz+marker+generator+circuit&rlz=1C1LDJZ_enGB499&espv=210&es_sm=93&tbm=isch&tbo=u&source=univ&sa=X&ei=05EfU-S_PInF7AaZpIHQDg&ved=0CC8QsAQ&biw=1231&bih=916

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks, I had seen those. It's mostly extracts from larger instruments, not schematics for standalone units, and few if any actual crystal-driven 10.7MHz oscillators to be seen. Not that useful without a bit of prior sorting and selection, and I'm not necessarily competent to do either.

Comment: @tcrosley Exactly. I've clarified, not that a request for a schematic should need it IMHO. Close-votes please note. There isn't a word about product recommendations in this post.

Comment: I have precisely the same question for precisely the same reason (ST-1000A). I also have an SG165 with a schematic. It has a 10.7mc marker injector built in. I am going to look at that circuit and the schematic for my HD-20 100kc crystal calibrator (that runs off a 9v) and see if I can make heads or tails on what ST may have originally had in their mystery box.